# Burninate the [letter] and [letters] tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

I don't see any case where the [letter](/questions/tagged/letter) tag could be useful (or [letters](/questions/tagged/letters) for that matter). [Questions tagged with this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letter) are always tagged with a programming language, which is much more pertinent.

Should it be Burninated?

Comment: Ha, I was about to suggest the same after rejecting your tag wiki proposals. :)

Comment: "alphabetic" can probably go along with them.

Comment: @Bart I realized it was useless just after writing them ;)

Comment: After scanning through the questions with this tag, I think it might be best to put [tag:letter] as a synonym of [tag:character] and prune out the few questions that are not about characters. While 'letter' and 'character' are not exactly the same, as far as programming challenges go, the difference between those two doesn't really matter.